# How to pass a JavaScript Array to ASP.Net MVC Action as part of post

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a cshtml as follow,

DoPost.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Purchase", "PurchaseOrder", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmPurchase" }))
{

// statements

// statements

<input type="button" id="submitPurchase" onclick = "myPurchase()" value="Select" />
}
```

In `Javascript` I have an array strings in variable "`ExtraItems`"

```
ExtraItems[0] ="123"
ExtraItems[1] ="124"
ExtraItems[2] ="125"
```

My Action which accept the data is as follows,

```
public ActionResult Purchase(PurchaseOrderModel model)
        {            
            //Do some stuff with the passed data
            return View("Purchase", model);
        }
```

In the above `PurchaseOrderModel`, I have the property

```
public string[] SelectedProducts { get; set; }
```

to accept the Javascript Array elements.

What I tried:
The simple post did not work as the JavaScript array elements are not part of the Form elements,I couldn't use a `@Html.HiddenFor` because it is an array.

Hence tried to do an Ajax post under function `myPurchase()`,

```
$a.post('@Url.Action("Purchase", "PurchaseOrder")', { SelectedProducts: ExtraItems });
```

Here I did not get the `ExtraItems` details under `model.SelectedProducts` in the action. The biggest issue was i wanted to load the `Purchase.cshtml` View from the action, instead I got the controll back to the Jquery Post.

Please help me how can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a string property in your model and then send the data as comma separated string

```
var dataToSent = ExtraItems.join(',')
```

If you have a property named Datum of type `string` in your model Purchase then the data to be sent will be, passing model

```
data : 'Datum=' + dataToSent
```

In your action you can split data into array
also for return response you have to redirect the page in the `success` function of your ajax call

```
$.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Default1/Index',
        data: { SelectedProducts: ExtraItems },

        traditional: true,
        success: function ( response )
        {
            window.location.href = "/controller/action" <--your url


        }
    } );
```

Comment: No I need to pass a model too. return View("Purchase", model); The model is updated with the ExtraItems data. So it is not possible to pass using window.location, as the model has too much data.

Comment: @TBA write the response to the screen . .document.write(response)

Comment: you should consider this post : [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

You should post your javascript array as a json object. You use the JSON.stringify() method converts a value to JSON. Something like :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Purchase", "PurchaseOrder")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
            SelectedProducts: ExtraItems
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, The problem is it is not doing the return View("Purchase", model); part. I came back to my success part of Ajax but no redirection.

Answer (score 2):

```
Here is my example for solving your issue
-----------------------------------------
//Script
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script>
    var ExtraItems = ["aa","bb","cc","ff"];
    function a()
    {
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Default1/Index',
            data: { SelectedProducts: ExtraItems },

            traditional: true,
            success: function ( response )
            {
                alert( 'Sucs' );


            }
        } );
    }

</script>
<button onclick="a();">click</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

//Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index( string[] SelectedProducts )
        {
              return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Arun But, I get the success and Alert too, however the return View(); part does't work??

Comment: Do you want to redirect to another view?

Comment: You cant redirect through return View() when using ajax.You should redirect from javascript.success: function ( response )
        {
            window.location.href = "/controller/action" <--your url


        }

Comment: Sorry I have some model to be passed to the view which is pretty big. Return View("Purchase", model). I think then I should post this data right?

Comment: Ok then you use a hidden field.Save that array to hidden field and bind it to model

Comment: How could I save the array to a hidden field? I thought that is not possible?

Comment: I tried with this this $("#SelectedProducts").val(SelectedItemIds); not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.ajax` function with the option `traditional:true` for enabling ASP.NET MVC default model binding for the list of string items.

Comment: Thanks, The problem is it is not doing the return View("Purchase", model); part. I came back to my success part of Ajax but no redirection.